# How to disable input field history using html

Tags: html, css

I want to disable the previously searches from my text input field. You know, the little box that pops up under the search bar with suggestions while you're typing ? Here, I'll attach a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply set `autocomplete="off"` on your input element.

```
<input name="yourname" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I knew that was it but for some reason I couldn't get it to work  but I got it now.

Comment: What! I was cracking my head trying to figure out the JavaScript code to do the job and here you are with a simple html solution. Thank you so much, it worked